# Multiple radio buttons naming problem

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

i have a bit of logical problem here. I have a catalog of products that have unique ids  and options that are displayed to the user through radio buttons. Now my problem is that a user must be able to select different options (from different products) and to submit them to a PHP script that handles this request (via POST). The problem is that the listed products are in one form, and to be able select multiple radio buttons i have to make them with unique names (and to handle the posted choices i have to guess the name of the button). Is there a way to make all the selected choices into array or something, cause otherwise i have to guess the POST-ed field every-time. I need to just pass the id and the options related to him, so i can extract the information from DB.

And one more what is the most convinient way to store selected choices through multiple pages (a.k.a paging - loaded through ajax) - cookies or temp variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using Checkboxes rather than Radio buttons - if you want multiple selection

Comment: Yeah that was my first though, but it want be looking that good as the radio buttons

Comment: Im not sure why you think it wont look as good. Using Radio Buttons for multiple selection is very inconsistant with the usual user experience. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511488.aspx - 'Is this the right control' section

Comment: Good point, i'll make it with checkboxes. Thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barrylloid.

then, if you name all your checkboxes something like

```
product1_select[]
```

then you should be able to read the values of the selected boxes in the PHP backend using

```
$_POST['product1_select']
```

Good luck!